# asyncio.run method not available in python 3.7.1?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have this example file:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)  # 3.7.1

import asyncio

async def hello_world():
    print('Hello World')

asyncio.run(hello_world())
```

I'm using pipenv to determine the python version to run:

```
$ pipenv run python --version
Python 3.7.1
```

Here is the output of running the code using python 3.7.1:

```
$ pipenv run python ./asyncio.py 
3.7.1 (default, Jan  2 2019, 19:26:38) 
[Clang 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
3.7.1 (default, Jan  2 2019, 19:26:38) 
[Clang 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./asyncio.py", line 18, in <module>
    import asyncio
  File "/Users/integralist/code/python3.7/asyncio.py", line 23, in <module>
    asyncio.run(hello_world())
AttributeError: module 'asyncio' has no attribute 'run'
```

I'm not sure why python 3.7.1 wouldn't have that run attribute?

I've also tried with python 3.7 but it's the same error?

Comment: Don't use the names of standard library modules for your modules.  Change the name of your file to something other than `asyncio.py`

Comment: ha! oh that's embarrassing. Thanks @PatrickHaugh